# Open 2 terminals using system() and select default for output

Tags: c, linux, gnome-terminal

I have a simple program like this

```
int main(void) {

    system("gnome-terminal");
    puts("terminal 1");
    system("gnome-terminal");
    puts("terminal 2");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

At runtime:
Opens only the first terminal and only when I close it the program continues, prints in the console and opens the second.

How can I open both of them?
(without stopping my program's execution when the first is open)

How can I selectively print in the two terminals inside of my program?
(puts("something"); at second terminal)

Thanks

Comment: one way is:  'system("gnome-terminal &");' which will run the terminal application in background (it will still be visible on the screen) and system() will promptly return, allowing your program to continue.   Sorry, cannot help with how to direct stdout to a specific terminal

Comment: Why do you want to do that? And why would you want to write into a `gnome-terminal` output programmatically? terminal emulators like `gnome-terminal` are not designed for that!

Comment: @user3629249 thanks! :) - It also works using system("gnome-terminal"); in a new thread.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's for a project in one off my courses. I've to extend the uncompleted, given, functions of a tiny os that runs on simple virtual machine. This tinyos supports 1 to 4 terminals. I think it's right to say that each terminal is like a user for the tiny os. So each user can have simultaneous interaction with the tinyos via the terminal and execute a couple of simple programs that the tinyos supports. I could open 1-4 terminals before executing the tinyos and then direct the tinyos to find and communicate with them but I prefer to open them during the virtual boot of the os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible because `system` blocks until the executed program ends, one possible solution is to use `fork()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++i)
    {
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            printf("terminal %d\n", 1 + i);
            system("gnome-terminal");
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

if you want to comunicate with the executed program, read [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen). And you might also be interested in [`execv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) and family.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - `system("gnome-terminal &")` works just fine.

Comment: the answer being incorrect and something else also working aren't the same thing

Comment: @user4815162342 my answer is not incorrect, what you suggest is just the same thing, with the `&` the sell will span a new process using `fork()`, so don't claim that my answer is incorrect just because you fail to understand it. And if you think your answer is better, feel free to post it, when I search for answers on SO I read all the possibilities.

Comment: The part claiming that "that is not possible because `system` blocks until the executed program ends" is simply incorrect. As shown in the previous comment, `system()` can be trivially instructed not to wait for the command to finish.

Comment: You are absolutely wrong, completely wrong, please read the `system` manual. `system()` does wait for the called program to exit and in fact it returns the program's `exit` code, what you are doing is telling the shell to terminate immediatly after calling the program and to execute the program in a new process via `fork()`, also read what the `&` means in the shell.

Comment: thank you guys :D I used both solutions and worked.
I think I will finally create a function for the opening of the terminal and execute it in two new threads.
(For my second question) Iharob I will read the functions you mentioned, thanks!

Comment: You misunderstand. The first sentence of your answer is incorrect because `system()` can be used to invoke `gnome-terminal` (or any other program) without waiting for it to finish. What you describe in the comment is a (correct) description of how this is implemented.

Comment: No, `system()` cannot be used to invoke any program without waiting for it to finish, for that you need `fork()`. Whether you make the shell call `fork()` or you call it yourself, that's a different thing. **`system()` cannot be used to invoke a program without waiting for it's exit code**, that's a feature of the shell where you are running the program who called `system()`.

Comment: The way you invoke the program has nothing to do with the way the standard function `system()` works. `system()` does wait for the program to finish, but when you do `program &` the shell executes the program in a new process created via `fork()` so the shell returns immediately.

Comment: `system()` waits for the shell to finish, but not (necessarily) the program you actually mean to invoke, in this case `gnome-terminal`. This is what the OP was interested in. The first sentence of your answer makes it sound like you *have* to use `fork()` to avoid waiting, which is incorrect. But you alreay acknowledged as much, so we are now talking in circles.